# How to change data in vue-component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

In Vue component I have some data that comes from a localStorage.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("user") !== null) {
  const obj_user = localStorage.getItem('user');
  var user = JSON.parse(obj_user);
} else {
  user = null;
}
return {
  user
}
```

After in this component I have to check this data. I do it like this

```
  <li v-if="!user"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  <li v-if="user">
    <a href="#"><span>{{user.name}}</span></a>
  </li>
```

But the data does not change immediately, but only after the page is reloaded. Right after I login in on the page and redirected the user to another page, I still see the Login link.
What am I doing wrong?
Maybe there is some other way how to check and output data from the localstorage in component?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: By the way, if receive data through a prop, same props:['user'] - the problem is the same

Comment: Where in your component are you setting these variables? Also you should try and be more consistent with your use of `const` and `let` instead of `var`. Additionally you should use a `v-if="!user"` and then on the next `li` do a `v-else`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue may be related to they way that your `user` variable is not a piece of reactive stateful data. There isn't quite enough code in your question for us to determine that for sure, but it looks like you are close to grasping the right way to do it in Vue.

I think my solution would be something like this...

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadUser() {
      let user = null;
      if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
        const obj_user = localStorage.getItem("user");
        user = JSON.parse(obj_user);
      }
      this.user = user;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.loadUser();
  }
}
```

I save the `user` in the `data` area so that the template will react to it when the value changes.

The `loadUser` method is separated so that it can be called from different places, like from a user login event, however I'm making sure to call it from the component's `created` event.

In reality, I would tend to put the `user` into a Vuex store and the `loadUser` method in an action so that it could be more globally available.

Comment: I Tried to do it. And have see error like this
 error    'user' is not defined

Comment: Calling `this.loadUser();` in `mounted()` instead of `created()` might do the trick. Depends what the rest of your code is doing.

Comment: Does not matter  'user' is not defined

Comment: The rest of my code is do nothing. This is one task of this component. Check data from localStorage

Comment: Found and fixed a bug   'user' is not defined 
In data()
Instead of user; I wrote user: this.user
It is work, but as before, only after page reload

Comment: Apparently localStorage loads data after the component has been rendered the page. Tried three different ways to dynamically show data from Storage, always the same (work only after reloading page). I would be grateful if you can tell me another way.

Comment: @АлександрМихалькевич Yes I left a bug in data()'s user property. Fixed it now by setting it to null initially. Is it possible that localStorage.getItem("user") is null? Are you setting it somewhere?

Comment: @NathanStrutz After login localStorage.getItem("user") is not null. And I have see all data from this storage in console.log(). But in component only after reloading page